# Deploy ruby on rails via Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I have successfully deployed my ruby on rails application to an ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine in **Digital Ocean**. I used **Apache2 and passenger** for the same.

Now I want to deploy it to the same using **Capistrano**. I am using a mac machine in the developer environment. I have installed Capistrano 3.4. ssh connection has been set up with my local machine and server as well as with my server and my mercurial version control system in bitbucket.

How can I deploy it via capistrano. I tried many tutorials. Many are outdated and I am not even close. I have deployed it in the server in **uat environment** and the source code is checked out and is kept in the desktop of server. I have also set up a user with sudo privileges.MySQl2 database is also in the same server.Please help me out .

Comment: start here http://capistranorb.com/ also check https://github.com/imnithin/capistrano3

Comment: see the railscasts for deploying code to VPS...it will clear away many doubts about how capistrano works behind the scenes....also see the commands in the deploy.rb  to understand what happens at the server remotely...

Answer (score 1):

You can see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/imtiaz-emu/dcb87fde71a9562037d2) here, there are 4 files

- deploy.rb
- production.rb
- capfile
- Gemfile // only the capistrano required gem snippet

But I've configured using nginx and passenger.

Comment: I am using capistrano 3.4..this one is for 3.1 right

Comment: This one is for 3.2.1 @NevinRajVictor

Comment: I didn't checked that. I guess it will do fine. or you can switch to the 3.2.1 version.

Comment: @Ebu: `cap -v` gave me 3.4. Now I did a `gem uninstall capistrano -v 3.4` and `gem install capistrano -v 3.2.1`. Now `cap -v` gives me  
`Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.` What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: after doing what the gist said, in your project directory run `cap production deploy:setup`. Try to read the errors while running this command. I guess the error will tell you to create a `database.yml` file on your `deploy_directory/shared/config/`. If the command runs without error then run `cap production deploy` that's it. It may also generate some errors then you need to figure out that too.

Comment: Same error on `cap production deploy:setup` ;  `Stage not set, please call something such as cap production deploy, where production is a stage you have defined`.

Comment: Do you created any `production.rb` file? If you just copied my code, then you need to modify that as per your requirement. I have commented the parts which you should modify in both `deploy.rb` and `production.rb`.

Comment: yes .. i have edited that..what about staging.rb file in deploy folder

Comment: `staging.rb` is a stage like `production.rb`, in your `/config/deploy/production.rb` file set stage production

Comment: How can I do a `bundle install`, `rake seed` tasks etc and restart my apache2 server in capistrano

Comment: Capistrano > 3 enables bundle install automatically. But if you need to run rake tasks then go to the server your project directory. then run manually. Or you can tell capistrano to run it in `deploy.rb` file. For this you need to see the capistrano documentation.